# PHP - using multiple IPv6 addresses to connect with remote server

Tags: php, linux, http, ipv6

I'm preparing to buy 1000 IPv6 addresses in my ISP provider to build a service for big data processing (calmly, I'm not a spammer :D)

My question is: **how can I connect to eg. google.com using my 843th address from venet0 interface?** **I preffer cURL** as I already wrote a HTTP class based on cURL.

Thank you for your time! Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm not good in English, so I have a trouble builiding a better search query to get any tips. I have nothing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting CURLOPT_INTERFACE?

> The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Good point! I read the manual but didn't notice this constant useful. Thank you!